# If $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu , \sigma)$ and $X=\log (1+Y)$ what distribution does $Y$ follow?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable such that

$$X \sim \mathcal N(\mu , \sigma)$$

Yf we define $Y$ like this: $X=\log (1+Y)$ what distribution does $Y$ follow?

I think that, $1+Y$ would follow a Log-Normal distribution, but how would I obtain the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: You mean, besides taking a $lognormal(\mu,\sigma)$ and shifting it left by 1 unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=\log(1+Y)$ then $Y=e^X-1$. Note that $e^X$ is $\operatorname{lognormal}(\mu,\sigma)$ so $Y=\operatorname{lognormal}(\mu-1,\sigma)$.

Comment: How can I demostrate that If $e^X$ is $lognormal(\mu,\sigma)$ then $Y=lognormal (\mu-1,\sigma)$? Thanks! :)

Comment: There's nothing to really show, but if you REALLY must compute something, note that $e^X$ and $-1$ are independent random variables and the distribution for a sum of random variables is the convolution of their distributions. Also note that the convolution of a function, $f(x)$ with $\delta(x+1)$ is $f(x+1)$. This is only if you REALLY want a computation to do.

Comment: Okey, Thanks a lot!:)